# Liquid templates - accessing members by name

Tags: ruby, templates, liquid, jekyll

I'm using [Jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) to create a new blog. It uses [Liquid](http://github.com/tobi/liquid) underneath.

Jekyll defines certain "variables": `site`, `content`, `page`, `post` and `paginator`. These "variables" have several "members". For instance, `post.date` will return the date of a post, while `post.url` will return its url.

My question is: **can I access a variable's member using another variable as the member name?**

See the following example:

```
{% if my_condition %}
  {% assign name = 'date' %}
{% else %}
  {% assign name = 'url' %}
{% endif %}
```

I have a variable called `name` which is either `'date'` or `'url'`.

**How can I make the liquid equivalent of `post[name]` in ruby?**

The only way I've found is using a `for` loop to iterate over all the pairs (key-value) of `post`. Beware! It is quite horrible:

```
{% for property in post %}
  {% if property[0] == name %}
    {{ property[1] }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Argh! I hope there is a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what I was thinking.

`post[name]` is a perfectly valid liquid construction. So the for-if code above can be replaced by this:

```
{{ post[name] }}
```

I thought that I tried this, but apparently I didn't. D'oh!

Liquid admits even fancier constructs; the following one is syntactically correct, and will return the expected value if `post`, `element`, `categories`, etc are correctly defined:

```
{{ post[element.id].categories[1].name }}
```

I am greatly surprised with Liquid. Will definitively continue investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this did not work for me. I tried a bunch of different combinations and what finally worked was

```
<!-- object myObj.test has the string value "this is a test" -->
{% assign x = 'test' %}
{{ myObj.[x] }}
```

Output:
this is a test